# How Do I Put the Bulletpoint Before the Theorem/Proof/Example/Etc. in Itemized List in Beamer Slides

Tags: beamer, itemize, ubuntu

I am using LaTeX on Ubuntu 20.04. I had everything working, then uninstalled something, which caused part of the LaTeX packages to be uninstalled, and I re-installed the LaTeX packages, and now when I do an Example (or Definition or Theorem or Proof, etc.) in Beamer, the bulletpoint comes after the Example, not before it on the same line.

Is there something I can do to get the bullet to come before the Example?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,enumerate,url,graphicx,wasysym}
\usepackage{movie15,MnSymbol}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{diagrams}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\beamertemplateshadingbackground{red!10}{blue!10}
\beamertemplateboldtitlepage \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\beamertemplateboldcenterframetitle
\renewcommand{\raggedright}{\leftskip=0pt \rightskip=0pt plus 0cm }

\newenvironment{Def}{\begin{block}{Definition}}{\end{block}}
\newenvironment{Claim}{\begin{block}{Claim}}{\end{block}}
\newenvironment{Fact}{\begin{block}{Fact}}{\end{block}}
\newenvironment{Result}{\begin{block}{Result}}{\end{block}}
\newenvironment{Solution}{\begin{block}{Solution}}{\end{block}}

\renewenvironment{proof}{\begin{block}{Proof}}{\end{block}}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

\newcommand{\none}[1]{}

\none{
\theoremstyle{definition}
%\newtheorem{Theorem}[theorem]{Theorem} 
\newtheorem{Thm}[theorem]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Lem}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Conj}[theorem]{Conjecture}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Def}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{Ex}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{Claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{Fact}[theorem]{Fact}
}

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\author{Dr. Jeffrey Rolland}
\institute{Math 001 - Intro to Counting \\
Department of Mathematics \\
My School}
\date{Fall, 2020}

\begin{document}

\title{Test Section}

\frame{\titlepage}

\frame
{

\frametitle{Test Frame} 

\begin{itemize}
    
    \item<+-> \begin{Example} This is an example; the bulletpoint appears after and a line below. \end{Example} 
    \item<+-> Here, the bulletpoint appears before and on the same line. I would like all bulletpoints like this one.
    
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Beamer Frame]

(Sorry about all the packages, I copy/pasted.) Is there any way to get the bulletpoints for Examples to appear before and on the same line as the Example?

Comment: I don't think your problem is relevant to `ubuntu`, as I can reproduce it on a different OS. Therefore, I recommend removing its tag.

Answer (score 1):

Surrounding the `Example` with a `minipage` and adding some `\vspace` commands to adjust the position and spacing, results in the following more minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Ex}[theorem]{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame} 

\begin{itemize}
    \item \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
            \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}
            \begin{Example} 
              This is an example; the bulletpoint appears after and a line below. 
            \end{Example}
            \vspace{0.25\baselineskip}
          \end{minipage}
    \item Here, the bulletpoint appears before and on the same line. I would like all bulletpoints like this one.
    \item the next item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this looks great (Again, sorry for all the "extra stuff" in my "minimal example")!

Is there a way to put all this stuff with the item/minipage/Example in some sort of "wrapper" that I can just invoke in lieu of literally invoking Example/Definition/Theorem/Proof/etc.? It would just same some copying/pasting in the ~16 .pdfs/class I have for the upcoming online quarter.

Again, thanks so much!

Comment: @Jeffrey Rolland You can try to modify leandriis answer to define this custom environment `\newenvironment{itemexample}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}\begin{Example}}{\end{Example}\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}\end{minipage}}` in the preamble, and then in your main doc use the command `\begin{itemexample} This is an example.... \end{itemexample}` after any `\item`.

Comment: @hesham Thanks so much! Now, I just need to write a bash script and run it on all my source files ("v-bashing" instead of "v-grepping"?). Seriously, I can't thank you enough